# QNX - two partitions mounted to same mounting point, change mountpoints order, or select the targeted partition?

Tags: mount, qnx

I have two partitions mounted to the same mounting point in the filesystem.

The partitions have explicitly set a precedence, to resolve filename in a desired order.

Assuming Partition A is mounted before any other partition and partition B is mounted after all other partitions.
Every time when I point to some pathname, the system, at first, looks at the partition A, and in case it is not able to resolve the filename, it looks at the partition B.

**The question is, how can I 'dynamically' change this order or explicitly points the desired partition?**

**Second issue.. perhaps it is possible to replicate the partition B mounting point under additional location ? Something like mount --bind under QNX ?**

I know I can umount and mount partitions again, but this is not an option.
Also I'm not able to change the mounting order of the partition by the remount, even if I explicitly set the 'after' flag for the partition A.

Comment: What is qnx version you use ???

Comment: If you have , for example 6.4.0,  then put here contents of  `/etc/rc.d`

Comment: The problem is solved. I begged the platform team to change to mounting points, and make them unique.